# simple php voting system doesn't update the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
session_start();
$host        =    'localhost';
$user        =    'root';
$password    =    '8******8';
$database    =    'tg*****ba';

$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or 
  die('Server Information is not Correct'); 

//Establish Connection with Server
mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');
$InGameName    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InGameName']);
$LastVoteTime;

//===When I will Set the Button to 1 or Press Button to register
if(isset($_POST['btnVote'])) 
{
  if(md5($_POST['code']) != $_SESSION['key']) 
    die("You've entered a wrong code!");
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entities WHERE Name = '". $InGameName ."'"); 
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 0) 
  { 
     die("This In game name doesn't exist , please enter your account name not username!");
  }
  else
  {
    $date = date('YmdHis');
    $row=mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $lastvote=$row->LastVoteTime;
    $votingpoints = $row->VotsPoints;
    $url = "http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?site=***********";

    if(($lastvote + 120000) < $date)
    {
      $lastvote = $date;
      $votingpoints += 1;
      $query = mysql_query("update entities set VotsPoints ='$votingpoints' set LastVoteTime ='$lastvote' WHERE Name = '". $InGameName ."'"); 
    }
    else
      die("You've Already voted in the last 12 hrs!");
  }
}

?>
```

It does not update the database with the votingpoints and lastvotetime
however it pass the first check (which means it found the account record in the database) but it doesn't set them in the end of that code
thanks in advance

Comment: mysql is depriciated...shift to PDO or Mysqli please

Comment: thank you but that won't fix this code and i need this page to be done asap

Comment: MySQL isn't deprecated.  The PHP extension `ext/mysql`, which provides all functions prefixed `mysql_` is deprecated as of PHP v5.5 (which is currently only in alpha release).

Comment: @eggyal: ext/mysql has been unofficially deprecated for years.  The only reason it's survived so long is all the dinosaur code (and all the w3schools dropouts) still using it.  But it's maintenance only, and has had the red warning boxes in the PHP docs for a while now (even before 5.5 hit alpha, AFAIR).

Comment: @cHao: Not quite sure what "unofficial deprecation" is, but I'm well aware that the manual has warned against its use in new code (since July 2011 - not quite "years").  In any event, I was merely trying to avoid any misunderstanding over NewBee's comment that "mysql is deprecated" which could easily be interpreted to mean that MySQL server itself is deprecated.

Comment: @eggyal: "Unofficially deprecated" means they were not-all-that-subtly trying to get people to stop using it for quite a while, even before they put up the red boxes.  Probably so they could *officially* deprecate it without a bunch of w3schools junkies whining about Y U DISABLE MY DATABASE?!!!?!!11!? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = mysql_query("update entities set VotsPoints = '$votingpoints', LastVoteTime = '$lastvote' WHERE Name = '". $InGameName ."'");
```

You're using "set" multiple times, not sure if that's ok.

Comment: thank you , that fixed the problem , once the time limit is over ill accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect on the UPDATE statement.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html